# How do I add html/javascript to an existing gwt application?

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt

We have a GWT application coded in java on the client. There is no ui binder only a jsp page and a class with our onModuleLoad() method and then pure java serving the gui. We want to add bunch of html/javascript to a new part of the application but I don't know how to organize the new html/javascript part. The new part will most likely contain a lot of html/js + js frameworks. Can someone please share how to do this?

(Side note: I am 95% a java dev and 5% web dev so an example would be great)

Comment: Can this new part be a different module? You can then inherit this module in your app's main module file. Also, you should consider using uiBinder instead of serving UI from pure Java.

Comment: Yes it can be an independent module but I would like it to be non-gwt related at all if possible. Moving to uibinder is not possible at this point.